# DB2 Query to Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, db2, criteria

I have a specific DB2 query, and I would like to execute this query using criteria.

The query:

```
SELECT
 sum(units) as volume,
 location_id, 
 aged
FROM (
 SELECT
   units,
   location_id,

   CASE
    WHEN daysinstock < 61 THEN 'NOT_AGED'
    WHEN daysinstock < 91 THEN 'AGED'
    ELSE 'OVER_AGED'
   END AS AGED 

  FROM 
   STOCK_TABLE
) x
group by location_id, aged
```

the STOCK_TABLE contains the following fields: units, location_id, daysinstock.
This table is matched by a StockDataSource object, with the same fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not available in the good ol' Hibernate Criteria API. Better write a [HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) for this. Or, if you're actually using Hibernate for JPA2, then you can use [`CriteriaBuilder.Case`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.Case.html).

Comment: Already was afraid it would not be... HQL is not really an option... I think I will create 3 seperate queries instead...